# select the rows of a table according to an id that is in a JSON in a column of the table

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I need to select the rows of a table according to the id In a JSON In one of the columns using Pandas.

example :

| column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | bbbbb | {'id' : cc, 'name' : xx ...} |
| xxxx | yyyy | {'id' : ff, 'name' : gg ...} |

so I want to select all the rows where the id of the JSON in the column_c is equal to 'cc', So the result will be :

| column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | bbbbb | {'id' : cc, 'name' : xx ...} |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

def func(x): #x is a string of json format
    s=json.loads(x)
    return s['id']=='cc'
```

And filter the dataframe by applying the above function to column_c:

```
df[df['column_c'].apply(lambda x: func(x)]
```

If this doesn't work, it means that column_c is of a different type. In that case, please provide the type of this column so that i will adjust the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have already loaded this into pandas it is probably now a dictionary which can be accessed by key similar to the dataframe so you are looking to filter like this:

```
df[df['column_c']['id'] == 'cc']
```